# Can we access DEX using Solidity?

Tags: solidity, decentralized-exchange

Basically, want to know if Solidity can be used to access / trade in decentralized exchanges. If so, how to link both.

Answer (score 1):

Solidity is a compiler, it generates executable code for Ethereum Virtual Machine.

DEX is a set of contracts that let you move tokens from one hand to another. These contracts where compiled by Solidity.

To access DEX and be able to exchange tokens as an end user you need a friendly App. Or, if you are an advanced user, you need a Wallet that can send particular `extra data` to the contract. The creators of the exchange must tell you how to interact with the contract and how to assemble the `extra data` field of the transaction.

Comment: Solidity is the language, `solc` is the compiler that creates the bytecode.

Comment: Thanks @Nulik . Can you please let know if I can use GAStoken using Solidity on a decentralized exchange to reduce GAS required for a transaction?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write a solidity smart contract to access/trade in decentralized exchanges.

You link both of them by using they're inheriting their smart contract code and using the provided functions for swapping. For example for swapping on uniswap through a smart contract you would need to use the import the router interface as `import '@uniswap/v3-periphery/contracts/interfaces/ISwapRouter.sol';`

Once you deploy your contract and run the functions your contract will automatically communicate with the DEX.

Check out the uniswap documentation for more:
https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/guides/swaps/single-swaps